# Can i access/use bundle identifier of xcode build project through unity?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Am really new to unity platform.
For my new project i've some flags setup in unity according to the bundle identifier stored on script.

What i want my code to do is access the bundle identifiers later from the ios build (xcode) and then setup the flags likewise.

Is there any unity script or plugin for that?
Any guide or references are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `BundleVersionBindings.BundleIdentifier`

```
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;

...
Debug.Log(BundleVersionBindings.BundleIdentifier);
...
```

Comment: i got this error "The type or namespace name `Purchasing' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Answer (score 0):

It's accessible in the editor via [UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.bundleIdentifier](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.html) and available at runtime via [UnityEngine.Application.bundleIdentifier](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.html).

Comment: how do i use "UnityEngine.Application.bundleIdentifier"

Comment: i get this error when i try it : `UnityEngine.Application' does not contain a definition for `bundleIdentifier'

am using unity_4.7

Comment: That error makes it seem like this is a new feature, but I'm afraid I can't help much more than that. I've only been using Unity for a few months and haven't worked in versions <5.3.

Comment: Before finding the Application class, I looked into using this project to track it, I'm not sure it's version compatibility either though: https://github.com/kayy/BundleVersionChecker

Comment: no it is not anymore